# Imitating the "IN" Operator

Tags: excel, operators, in-operator, vba

How can one achieve:

```
if X in (1,2,3) then
```

instead of:

```
if x=1 or x=2 or x=3 then
```

In other words, how can one best imitate the `IN` operator in VBA for excel?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I don't think there is a very elegant solution.

However, you could try:

```
If Not IsError(Application.Match(x, Array("Me", "You", "Dog", "Boo"), False)) Then
```

or you could write your own function:

```
Function ISIN(x, StringSetElementsAsArray)
    ISIN = InStr(1, Join(StringSetElementsAsArray, Chr(0)), _
    x, vbTextCompare) > 0
End Function

Sub testIt()
    Dim x As String
    x = "Dog"
    MsgBox ISIN(x, Array("Me", "You", "Dog", "Boo"))
End Sub
```

Comment: Couldn't you just avoid the function and use something like:
`InStr(1,"MeYouDogBoo",x)`?

Comment: @redOctober13 this could work if you separate the list items with a delimiter that cannot be found in x.  Otherwise, YouDo would trigger the InStr.

Comment: Be careful with this simple version of the **IsIn()** function.   It will return True if the search word is contained in any words in the passed array.  Searching for 'do' will return true because it's found in 'Dog'.   The better way is to make sure chr(0) is before and after the search word, and before and after the joined search string.

An example can be found here <http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=1675>

Comment: @Ben can you check that link, it appears to be broken. Also I wrote this response almost 10 years ago and you are correct that this could be improved.

Comment: @Kredns The address is correct but the link is passing the trailing '>' which was unintended.  Try this one:   [http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=1675](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=1675)

Comment: When tested, this method took **1.828 seconds** while **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52042455/8112776)** took only **0.406 seconds**. (Details in other answer.)

Answer (score 15):

You could also try the **CASE** statement instead of **IF**

```
Select Case X

 Case 1 To 3   
  ' Code to do something
 Case 4, 5, 6
  ' Code to do something
 Case 7
  ' Code to do something
 Case Else  
  ' More code or do nothing

End Select
```

Comment: How is this shorter than `if x=1 or x=2 or x=3 then` like the OP asked?

Comment: I think this is still a good answer, and my preferred option. You only need one case statement as values can be stacked:

`Select Case x
  Case 1,2,3
    ' Your code...
End Select`

Answer (score 9):

## Fastest Method:

Here's a method **much faster and more compact** than ***any*** of the other answers, and **works with numeric or text values:**

```VB
Function IsIn(valCheck, valList As String) As Boolean  
    IsIn = Not InStr("," & valList & ",", "," & valCheck & ",") = 0
End Function
```

---

### Examples:

**Use `IsIn` with a numeric value:**

```VB
Sub demo_Number()
    Const x = 2
    If IsIn(x, "1,2,3") Then
        Debug.Print "Value " & x & " was Found!"
    Else
        Debug.Print "Value " & x & " was not Found."
    End If
End Sub
```

**Use `IsIn` with a string value:**

```VB
Sub demo_Text()
    Const x = "Dog"
    If IsIn(x, "Me,You,Dog,Boo") Then
        Debug.Print "Value " & x & " was Found!"
    Else
        Debug.Print "Value " & x & " was not Found."
    End If
End Sub
```

---

### Speed Comparison:

To compare speed I ran the test from the accepted answer 100,000 times:

- `0.406 sec     (FASTEST)` **This Function** (using [InStr](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function)):
- `1.828 sec (450% slower)` Accepted [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1505248/8112776) with the "ISIN" function
- `1.799 sec (440% slower)` [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1505261/8112776) with the "IsInArray" from freeVBcode
- `0.838 sec (206% slower)` [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39960118/8112776) with modified "IsInArray" function

I didn't include the much longer [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1509089/8112776) that uses `SELECT..CASE` since the OP's goal was presumably to *simplify and shorten* the task compared to "`if x=1 or x=2 or x=3 then`".

Comment: Why complicate your function with the redundant `Not` and `= 0`?

Answer (score 2):

did you try

```
eval("3 in(1,2,3,4,5)")
```

Comment: I get "sub or function not defined" - don't know if this is because I am in VBA (not VB ) ?  have edited the question...

Comment: It is Access VBA function. Sorry I didn't see that you mentioned excel VBA.

Comment: ...so this isn't an answer to this question. Why is it still here?

Answer (score 1):

There's none that I'm aware of.

I usually use a home-brewed InArray() function like the one at http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=1675

You could also make a version that iterates through the array instead of concatenating, if that is more appropriate to your data type.

Comment: When tested, this method took **1.799 seconds** while **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52042455/8112776)** took only **0.406 seconds**.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work without writing your own function. Be aware that the accepted solution by @Kredns may not work as expected for all types of objects since they are coerced to strings (which also may raise Type Mismatch errors).

This solution should (hopefully) handle all types of data (at least in **Excel 365**, not sure about earlier versions):

```
Function IsIn(x As Variant, list As Variant) As Boolean
    ' Checks whether list (Array) contains the element x
    IsIn = False
    For Each element In list
        If x = element Then IsIn = True
    Next element
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dim x, y
x = 2
y = Array(1, 2, 3)

For i = 0 To 2
If x = y(i) Then
'your code comes here
Exit For
End If
Next i
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score -1):

I wrote it now...

```
Public Function IsInArray(FindValue As Variant, ParamArray arrEmailAttachment()) As Boolean

Dim element As Variant

For Each element In arrEmailAttachment
    If element = FindValue Then
        IsInArray = True
        Exit Function
    End If
Next element

IsInArray = False

End Function
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: When tested, this method took 0.838 seconds while **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52042455/8112776)** took only **0.406 seconds**.