# If active sheet code name equals then exit sub

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a why this code be shortened down to 1 line, Code works but would like to consolidate it.

```
'If active sheet has the code name below then exit this sub

If ActiveSheet.CodeName = "VPL" Then Exit Sub
If ActiveSheet.CodeName = "VBA_BlankBidSheet" Then Exit Sub
If ActiveSheet.CodeName = "VBA_BlankOptionSheet" Then Exit Sub
If ActiveSheet.CodeName = "VBA_Dropdowns" Then Exit Sub
```

Comment: take a look here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505206/imitating-the-in-operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont really understand your question...

You mean like use Or?

`If ActiveSheet.CodeName = "VPL"  Or ActiveSheet.CodeName = "VBA_BlankBidSheet" Or ActiveSheet.CodeName = "VBA_BlankOptionSheet" Or ActiveSheet.CodeName = "VBA_Dropdowns" Then Exit Sub`