# How to do if "=" multiple values?

Tags: excel, vba

I want a message to show if a user attempts to change a cell based on its column title. I could just protect the cells but it would be useful for future knowledge anyway.

Rather than multiple if statements I want something similar to the where in() that is in SQL. Is there a way of doing not in or would you just use an else?

Code that works for one value

```
Dim ThisColumn as long
ThisColumn=Target.Column
If Cells(1, ThisColumn).Value = "# workers" Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Undo
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    MsgBox "Protected Columns"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

I want something like

```
If Cells(1, ThisColumn).Value in("# workers","# of people") Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Undo
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    MsgBox "Protected Columns"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Imitating the "IN" Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505206/imitating-the-in-operator)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to use binary logical operators, like `AND` or `OR`, as explained here:

[AND-operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/and-operator)

[OR-operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/or-operator)

In your case, the `OR`-operator gives you following solution:

```
if ((Cells(1, ThisColumn).Value="# workers"  )  OR
    (Cells(1, ThisColumn).Value="# of people"))
...
```

Answer (score 1):

many thanks. I did try using the or function but it did not work (unless I needed the brackets around the ifs?. Please note that I have found a solution however and was more what I was looking for as I could define a list:

```
Dim ColumnTitle
ColumnTitle = Cells(1, ThisColumn).Value  
Select Case ColumnTitle    
Case "# Workers", "Assumption numbers used for costings"   ' List of Column Titles.

    Cells(ThisRow, ThisColumn).Select

Case Else    ' Other values.
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Undo
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    MsgBox "Protected Columns."

End Select
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use instr, please read: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38267950/check-if-a-value-is-in-an-array-or-not-with-excel-vba)

Ex:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Yourvalue As Variant
Dim ThisColumn as long
ThisColumn=Target.Column

Yourvalue = Array("# workers", "# of people", "# ...")
If IsInArray(Cells(1, ThisColumn).Value, Yourvalue) Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.Undo
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        MsgBox "Protected Columns"
    Exit Sub
    End If
'Continue Code

End Sub

Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Integer
IsInArray = InStr(Join(arr, ""), stringToBeFound)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Dictionary` and it's built-in method `Exists`

```
Dim RestrictedColumns As Object
Set RestrictedColumns = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
With RestrictedColumns
    .Add "# workers", "# workers"
    .Add "# of people", "# of people"
End With
Dim ThisColumn As Long
ThisColumn=Target.Column
If RestrictedColumns.Exists(Cells(1, ThisColumn).Value) Then
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Undo
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
    MsgBox "Protected Columns"
    Exit Sub
End If
```